# Why does ESRI Geodatabase Replica "Schema Compare" not identify changes?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, replication

I've made some schema changes (new fields to existing FCs), and would like to replicate the changes to the child.

While importing schema to the child database (which is the destination for a one-way replica from the parent), it shows a message saying *No schema changes found for this replica pair*

I did a previous schema change which had new fields and a couple of new FCs, and it worked fine. This time however, it is giving this message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...the approach (connected mode) we were following did not work.
I switched to the disconnected mode replica compare and it seems to find the differences (not all of them though).

Working with ESRI on this did not yield any fruitful result, as they were unable to provide any solution and maintained they could replicate on their test machines.

Finally, I moved to a third, and more convenient approach of modifying the source and destination both, using Python scripts.

I understand this could be possibly be a pain in the back with multi-level versioning scenarios, but for us it works best as there less scope of error and usually faster than a manual compare process as set out by ESRI.

Cheers!